# What is よ doing as a connector before a comma?

Tags: grammar, particles

I saw this as a comment someone posted on Google+ in response to NHK announcing a show:

> 本気{ほんき}なら地上波{ちじょうは}でやれ**よ**、受信料{じゅしんりょう}返{かえ}せ

I think it's saying "If this is really what you intend to broadcast, give me back my broadcast fees!"

I'm not confident in that, though, because of that `よ` that comes just before the comma. My translation is more because I can't think of anything else that makes sense.

So far as I know, `よ` is just a for emphasis. As such, I don't know if I've ever really noticed it being used in the middle of a sentence before. If it just emphasis, then we should be able to take it out, like this:

> 本気なら地上波でやれ、受信料返せ

Which to me looks incomplete. If I wanted to say in Japanese the same sentiment, I would use `ば`, like so:

> 本気なら地上波でやれ**ば**、受信料返せ

Is `よ` in the original sentence serving the same purpose as my `ば`, or is there something completely different going on?

What exactly is the best translation of the sentence, assuming mine is off?

Comment: They just look like separate clauses.  "If you're serious (about that/whatever), then broadcast it; give me back my fees."  Though I'm unsure of the translation, not really knowing the context.  I'd say there's a comma because they're closely enough related they don't need to be separate sentences, but not so closely that they *need* a connecting particle/grammar.

Comment: Post it as an answer :)

Comment: This is pretty simple. The punctuation is wrong. The text you posted should be 本気なら地上波でやれよ。受信料返せ。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd agree with SomethingJapanese and his/her translation, with one small edit, ("If you're serious (about that/whatever), then broadcast it **over regular terrestrial broadcast**; give me back my fees.") in the comments above.

They are two different clauses. You can imagine an English sentence that takes advantage of a comma splice to create the same effect: "If you're a real candidate, drop the birther issue, focus on the real issues."

And I think Japanese is a lot more tolerant of comma misuse. Also, this is from an Internet comment, which is far more casual than other writing.